# CSS - Break line link box

Tags: html, css, line-breaks

I'm trying to create a box with a linked text and a break line.

but, for some reason, when the line is break, the box is break too..

I try a lot of options but I cannot find the solution.

here is the https://jsfiddle.net/cbdnvm2t/

```
<br><br>
<a href="#" style="padding: 10px; border: 1pt solid #ea1d2a;">Line 1 <br> Line 2</a>

<br><br><br><br>
<a href="#" style="padding: 10px; border: 1pt solid #ea1d2a;"><span style="display:block">Line 1</span> <br><span style="display:block"> Line 2</span></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `display:block` to your `a` tag.

By default anchors are *inline* elements, not *block* elements - this is what is causing your box to split over two lines.

The following should work:

`<a href="#" style="display: block; padding: 10px; border: 1pt solid #ea1d2a;">Line 1 <br> Line 2</a>`

Comment: Using `display:inline-block` may be closer to the expected result. This avoids the link filling the entire width.

Comment: hi @adrian-lynch and brandon-gano, first of all tks for your time!! Both solutions works!! But Brandon solutions is a little better solution if you need a small box, in my case with only 10px of padding. tks a lot!!!